# Java Socket, binding to local port

Tags: java, sockets, client, port, socketexception

I am trying to bind the Socket on the client side to any particular local port, in this code I used 20000.

Normal connections such as below works just fine. But does not allow for me to choose the local port.

```
hostSocket = new Socket(host,80);
```

So I tried this:

```
hostSocket = new Socket(host, 80, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 20000);
```

and this:

```
hostSocket = new Socket();
hostSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 20000));
hostSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,80));
```

But they both leave me with this exception... in the second case the exception occurred on the connect call. I'm not really sure what I am missing and I would love some pointers.

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
at com.mb.proxy.netflix.NetflixPrefetchingAgent.connect(NetflixPrefetchingAgent.java:98)
at com.mb.proxy.netflix.NetflixPrefetchingAgent.run(NetflixPrefetchingAgent.java:164)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Exception in thread "Thread-19" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mb.proxy.netflix.NetflixPrefetchingAgent.prefetchChunk(NetflixPrefetchingAgent.java:272)
at com.mb.proxy.netflix.NetflixPrefetchingAgent.run(NetflixPrefetchingAgent.java:176)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Why do you care what the outbound local port is?

Comment: @Brian Roach I'm throttling bandwidth on particular ports for research purposes. For it to work I need to know which ports certain parts of my application are using.

Comment: I believe you have to bind to the actual outbound IP address (not localhost which is going to resolve to 127.0.0.1) - I'd have to test it though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to bind to the external (outbound) IP address of your machine, not localhost (127.0.0.1).

The following works on my box without issue:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("172.16.1.102", 5000));
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));
```

Where `172.16.1.102` is the NAT'd private network address assigned to this box via DHCP from my router.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I just tested it and it works. Sorry I don't have the appropriate amount of reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: HELLO @BrianRoach we should not bind and connect to the same InetSocketAddress ie the server ?? it is like we need to bind to one socketaddress and connect to another ? i was bit confused. could you please clarify this

Answer (score 4):

Brian's answer is spot on in identifying the issue.

However, you don't need the IP address of the outbound interface because you can simply specify `0.0.0.0` for "any address".  The correct outbound interface will then be chosen automatically.  This is much like when you connect without binding first.

Moreover, the [easiest way to specify `0.0.0.0` as the address is to omit the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733183#14740152).

Therefore:

```
hostSocket = new Socket();
hostSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(20000));
hostSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80));
```